# Count the number of half-days `entity_a` happens on

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Context**

I have two tables `entity_a`  and `entity_b`. The `entity_b` is linked to `entity_a` through a foreign key, and has another field `date`, which is a `date` (not a datetime, not a timestamp). The `date` field of `entity_b` indicates when `entity_a` happens.

**Problem**

I want to count of number of half-days where `entity_a` is happening. However to do that, I don't take into account the time of `entity_b` (I don't make the rules, and no I don't think they make sense either), just the number of `entity_b` per date: on one day, if there are more than two, count 1 day, if there is 1, count 0.5 day.

In other words, each `entity_b` counts for `0.5`, for a maximum of `1` per date.

As one more constraint: I want to return one row for each `entity_a`, since I'll be querying multiple at time

Note: using Postgres

**Example**

In this example, `entity_a_1` has 1.0 day, `entity_a_2` has 1.5 days

- entity_a_1

  - entity_b (2023-05-01)
  - entity_b (2023-05-02)
- entity_a_2

  - entity_b (2023-05-12)
  - entity_b (2023-05-13)
  - entity_b (2023-05-13)
  - entity_b (2023-05-13)

**Thing I've tried**

first, for those who want to test at home: the schema and data of the example

```sql
CREATE TABLE entity_a (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE entity_b (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, a_id INTEGER REFERENCES entity_a(id), date DATE);
INSERT INTO entity_a (id) VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT INTO entity_b (a_id, date) VALUES (1, '2023-05-01'), (1, '2023-05-02'), (2, '2023-05-12'), (2, '2023-05-13'), (2, '2023-05-13'), (2, '2023-05-13');
```

I have tried things that did the job using a subquery but with very poor performance:

```sql
SELECT
  a.id,
  SUM(b_agg.count)
FROM
  entity_a a
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      b.a_id,
      CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0.5
      END AS count
    FROM
      entity_b b
    GROUP BY
      b.a_id,
      b.date
  ) b_agg ON b_agg.a_id = a.id
GROUP BY
  a.id;
```

(if you use the data from the example, it will obviously be very fast, but consider there are millions of rows in each table)
(here's a small bash script that will fill the tables with a million lines. It's far from reality, yet a little closer `for i in {3..1000000}; do; psql --command "INSERT INTO entity_a (id) VALUES ($i); INSERT INTO entity_b (a_id, date) VALUES ($i, '2023-01-01')"; done`)

And I had the feeling window functions could help, but I don't know much about them so I always ended up failing to use them correctly

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe window functions will help. If you remove the `join` because it isn't required here, the query will be faster:

```
SELECT a_id, SUM(count) as count_
FROM (
  SELECT
      b.a_id,
      CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0.5
      END AS count
    FROM
      entity_b b
    GROUP BY
      b.a_id,
      b.date
) AS t
group by t.a_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Honestly, I kinda feel bad the solution was so simple  I had to adapt the query because I actually needed the `JOIN`, but moving it inside the subquery made the query much faster. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution via window functions. I don't know if you'll find that it runs better but it's worth checking into:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        case when date = lag(date) over (partition by a_id order by date)
            then 0.0
            else case when date = lead(date) over (partition by a_id order by date)
                then 1.0 else 0.5 end
        end as weight
    from entity_b
)
select a.id, sum(weight) as total
from entity_a a inner join entity_b b on b.a_id = a.id
group by a.id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/Az4y03-0

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! It does improve the performance indeed  I chose the other solution because it was even faster, but thanks anyway it helped me understand a little bit more about window functions too 